# Getting Fatal Error upon setting up new webshop

Tags: magento-1.6

I am currently working a project where I am setting up a new webshop, I am still relatively new but have had success in the past, this time, after transferring all files to the new FTP server and having the backend in good conditions for transfer, such as compiler off / caches disabled etc.

I get the following error immidiately upon saving something once I try to save my back-end, in system -> config :/

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product' not found in /data/sportnor/public_html/multifitness.dk/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1350"
```

I thought I messed up the file transfer and broke some files in the process, so I did it over again.. with no success.

EDIT:

```
    public function getModelInstance($modelClass='', $constructArguments=array())
{
    $className = $this->getModelClassName($modelClass);
    if (class_exists($className)) {
        Varien_Profiler::start('CORE::create_object_of::'.$className);
        $obj = new $className($constructArguments);
        Varien_Profiler::stop('CORE::create_object_of::'.$className);
        return $obj;
    } else {
        /* throw Mage::exception(
            'Mage_Core',
            Mage::helper('core')->__('Model class does not exist: %s.', $modelClass)
        ); */
        return false;
    }
}

public function getNodeClassInstance($path)
{
    $config = Mage::getConfig()->getNode($path);
    if (!$config) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $className = $config->getClassName();
        return new $className();
    }
}
```

codesnippet taken from line 1345 to 1371 from config.php

Regards

Comment: Does that file exist in your set?

Comment: config.php is present, i've looked in the file, but for the life of me I can't figure out if something is wrong, (not a magento developer) this was a complete copy of all files on a live FTP server to copy to a test server for changing the theme.

Comment: I've editted original post with codesnippet from config.php

Comment: I meant the class that apparently couldn't be found. It will be in app code core Mage Catalog Model Convert Adapter Product.php or should be at least

Comment: Hello again scrowler, sorry I don't know where it's located, I really want to check it though..

Comment: Thanks for the hint bud, I looked into it and found where the file was SUPPOSED to be, yet it wasn't there, when I did the file transfer on our FTP it didn't show up as a "failed transfer" - infact no files did, yet it didn't get transferred .. odd, I wonder how many more files are gone missing. At least it doesn't give me the error message anymore.

Now I have a new problem though.. Theme is saved, enabled, cache is flushed etc. but nothing to see, the website is just blank.. : \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so with a little bit of help from Mr. Scrowler in the replies section to my initial post, I found out that I was missing Product.php in:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php
```

The file simply got lost in the massive transfer to the new FTP server, simple error, I was very confused, so I hope this will help anyone who makes the same mistake.

Here's a link to where it says the directory and shows the code layout:

http://freegento.com/doc/d6/daf/_catalog_2_model_2_convert_2_adapter_2_product_8php-source.html

Comment: Why I try not to ftp alot of files. If you can drop an archive on your server and then extract it, it's much faster and more reliable. Of course, you can always perform a hash check as well to be sure your files transferred correctly.